# History of a grouped query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a problem and I think someone can help me here.

I have a sales table, with a reference to the product,the saleId and the price. At the moment I have a query, which does a group by product and send the grouped data back to the application. But now I would love to have a log, which entries I have grouped in this query. The problem is, that only the grouped entries are saved in another Stored Procedure, if the users saves it in the application.

My suggestion for this problem:
Before I do my group by query. I would save all entries in a new table with e temporary Id. Then I would send the temporary id with the data back to the application and if the users saves it, the temporary id would be saved in n:m table with the real ID.

What are your suggestions about this problem?

Comment: My first suggestion about this problem is to learn [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). And then to learn about [what kinds of details should I post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help!